# How to delegate pattern matching to a function in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, metaprogramming

I have a type like this:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Clone)]
enum MyEnum {
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo,
    Integer(i32),
    Text(String),
}
```

In my code I have a lot of similar patterns:

```rust
let value = match iterator.next() {
    Some(MyEnum::ValueOne) => MyEnum::ValueOne,
    Some(value) => return Err(format!("Unexpected value {:?}", value)),
    None => return Err("Unexpected end of input!"),
}
```

Or this:

```rust
let value = match iterator.next() {
    Some(MyEnum::Integer(i)) => MyEnum::Integer(i),
    Some(value) => return Err(format!("Unexpected value {:?}", value)),
    None => return Err("Unexpected end of input!"),
}
```

I would like to create a generic function `take_value`, where I can specify the `MyEnum` type I need, and it returns the `Result`

I can only solve it with simple values like this:

```rust
fn take_value(iterator: &mut Iterator<MyEnum>, expected: MyEnum) -> Result<MyEnum, String> {
    match iterator.next() {
        Some(expected) => Ok(expected),
        Some(value) => Err(format!("Unexpected value {:?}", value)),
        None => Err("Unexpected end of input!"),
    }
}
```

It can be called like this: `let value = take_value(iterator, MyEnum::ValueOne)?;`

But how is it possible to modify this function, so it can be called for MyEnum::Integer, without specifying the integer value inside? Like `take_value(iterator, MyEnum::Integer)`

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96d04948d301e295f6e7aeaf9831926e

Comment: @Stargateur I would like to specify what kind of value I expect, when I call take_value. Like MyEnum::Integer or MyEnum::ValueTwo

Comment: maybe see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409566/get-enum-discriminant-without-constructing-an-instance

Comment: I fail to see how the linked question is a duplicate, even if you'd use a `Discriminant` the only answer there isn't using one and is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with a function, but the macro below comes close to what you want.
Because we have to differentiate between patterns `:pat` and expressions `:expr` you have to repeat that part.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Clone)]
enum MyEnum {
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo,
    Integer(i32),
    Text(String),
}
macro_rules! take_value {
    ($iterator:expr, $pattern:pat, $expr:expr) => {
        match $iterator.next() {
            Some($pattern) => Ok($expr),
            Some(value) => Err(format!("Unexpected value {:?}", value)),
            None => Err("Unexpected end of input!".to_string()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut it = [MyEnum::ValueOne, MyEnum::ValueTwo, MyEnum::Integer(5)].into_iter();
    dbg!(take_value!(&mut it, MyEnum::ValueOne, MyEnum::ValueOne));
    dbg!(take_value!(&mut it, MyEnum::ValueOne, MyEnum::ValueOne));
    dbg!(take_value!(&mut it, MyEnum::Integer(i), MyEnum::Integer(i)));
    dbg!(take_value!(&mut it, MyEnum::ValueOne, MyEnum::ValueOne));
}
```

[outputs](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f5f7bfa618b9748e92d24b1045f2f5d)

```
…
src/main.rs:21] take_value!(& mut it, MyEnum :: ValueOne, MyEnum :: ValueOne) = Ok(
    ValueOne,
)
[src/main.rs:22] take_value!(& mut it, MyEnum :: ValueOne, MyEnum :: ValueOne) = Err(
    "Unexpected value ValueTwo",
)
[src/main.rs:23] take_value!(& mut it, MyEnum :: Integer(i), MyEnum :: Integer(i)) = Ok(
    Integer(
        5,
    ),
)
[src/main.rs:24] take_value!(& mut it, MyEnum :: ValueOne, MyEnum :: ValueOne) = Err(
    "Unexpected end of input!",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with this kind of "example value". You will need to pass a predicate callback to your `take_value` function:

```
fn take_value<F: Fn(&MyEnum) -> bool>(iterator: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = MyEnum>, predicate: F) -> Result<MyEnum, String> {
    match iterator.next() {
        Some(value) if predicate (&value) => Ok(value),
        Some(value) => Err(format!("Unexpected value {:?}", value)),
        None => Err("Unexpected end of input!".to_string()),
    }
}
```

which you then call like:

```
let value1 = take_value (&mut it, |v| v == &MyEnum::ValueOne);
let integer = take_value (&mut it, |v| matches!(v, MyEnum::Integer (_)));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8d7a0ba60ddad389f2187b21a4205bd)

Optionally, you can hide the fact that the predicate is a callback with a simple macro:

```
macro_rules! mk_pred {
    ($pat:pat) => {
        |v| matches!(v, $pat)
    }
}
```

which allows calling `take_value` like this:

```
let value1 = take_value (&mut it, mk_pred!(MyEnum::ValueOne));
let integer = take_value (&mut it, mk_pred!(MyEnum::Integer (_)));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3cf83fdbea81be0a9b4611bd7c54177)

Answer (score 0):

An approach that I see a lot in the wild, even if it has some boilerplate, is to simply create one conversion function per enum variant. For example:

```
impl MyEnum {
    pub fn as_value_one(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match self {
            MyEnum::ValueOne => Ok(()),
            _ => Err(self.unexpected_value()),
        }
    }

    pub fn as_integer(&self) -> Result<i32, Error> {
        match self {
            MyEnum::Integer(i) => Ok(*i),
            _ => Err(self.unexpected_value()),
        }
    }

    fn unexpected_value(&self) -> Error {
        format!("Unexpected value {:?}", self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let value = iterator.next()
    .ok_or_else(|| "Unexpected end of input!".to_owned())?
    .as_value_one()?;
let value: i32 = iterator.next()
    .ok_or_else(|| "Unexpected end of input!".to_owned())?
    .as_integer()?;
```

I left the `Option` outside of the implementation because it didn't seem to belong here, but you can do it however you like.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. How would you use this to write a function like the `take_value` that the OP wants?

Comment: You wouldn't. Other answers are already pointing out that it's impossible to write it exactly as asked, so I'm just offering another alternative.